# Dynamically sorting with IComparer

Tags: c#

I have the following code I would like reviewed. I was recently tasked with sorting products coming from SOLR. The sorting is not by description or by the product number but rather by the below criteria. Normally I use linq to use grouping and sorting, but in this case I have existing (older code) and *my approach was to be able to just plug in the new code without disturbing too much of the current code* by implementing the `IComparable` interface. My approach dynamically creates a list of unique products that has an associated sort position that is passed to `ProductSortComparer`.

I'm interested in feedback as well as perhaps a better approach.

**Sorting Criteria**

1. Sort by 10th position of the item number based of which group the char belongs to
2. Then sort by the Merchandiser Code

For example:

**10th position Item Number sort order**

```
 List<String> group1 = new List<String> { "E", "F", "G", "R", "C", "A" }; // top
 List<String> group2 = new List<String> { "B", "D", "S" };
 List<String> group3 = new List<String> { "J", "M", "Q" };
 List<String> group4 = new List<String> { "H", "I", "L" };
 List<String> group5 = new List<String> { "K", "N" }; // bottom
```

Merchandiser Codes (second level sort):

**MerchandiseCodes**

```
E = Everyone - Has to higher than A or G
A = Acedemic - Has to be lower than E
G = Government - Has to be lower than E
```

**Code:**

```
class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // build ArrayList of products
            ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

            Product product1 = new Product { 

                ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1B01",
                Description = "Dell Computer Support",
                MerchandiseCode = "E"

            };

            products.Add(product1);

            Product product2 = new Product
            {

                ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1E01",
                Description = "Acedemic Computer, DELL",
                MerchandiseCode = "A"

            };

            products.Add(product2);

            Product product3 = new Product
            {

                ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1E20",
                Description = "Government Computer, DELL",
                MerchandiseCode = "G"

            };

            products.Add(product3);

            Product product4 = new Product
            {

                ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1F01",
                Description = "Small Computer, DELL",
                MerchandiseCode = "E"

            };

            products.Add(product4);

            Product product5 = new Product
            {

                ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1M01",
                Description = "Dell Computer Repair",
                MerchandiseCode = "E"

            };
            products.Add(product5);

            // before sort
            Console.WriteLine("** Before Sort **");
            foreach (var product in products) {
                Product prod = product as Product;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}--{1}", prod.ItemNumber, prod.Description));            
            }
            ProductSortFactory sortFactory = new ProductSortFactory(products);
            products.Sort(sortFactory.GetComparer());
            Console.WriteLine("********************************");
            // after sort
            Console.WriteLine("** After Sort **");
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Product prod = product as Product;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}--{1}", prod.ItemNumber, prod.Description));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Product {

        public String ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String MerchandiseCode { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    public class ProductSortComparer : IComparer {

        public List<ProductSortAttribute> SortOrder { get; set; }
        public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
        {
            return obj.ItemNumber.GetHashCode();
        }


        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            Product product = (Product)x;
            Product otherProduct = (Product)y;

            if (this.SortOrder != null && this.SortOrder.Any())
            {
                // Find product in the index
                var thisTagged = this.SortOrder.Select((item, i) => new { Item = item, Index = (int?)i });
                int? thisIndex = (from pair in thisTagged
                                  where pair.Item.ItemNumber == product.ItemNumber
                                  select pair.Index).FirstOrDefault();

                var otherTagged = this.SortOrder.Select((item, i) => new { Item = item, Index = (int?)i });
                int? otherIndex = (from pair in otherTagged
                                   where pair.Item.ItemNumber == otherProduct.ItemNumber
                                   select pair.Index).FirstOrDefault();


                if (thisIndex > otherIndex)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (thisIndex < otherIndex)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if pos 10 not found in reference list treat both obj as equal
                    return 0;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }


        }
    }
```

```
    public class ProductSortAttribute : IComparable<ProductSortAttribute>
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public String ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }


        public int CompareTo(ProductSortAttribute other)
        {
            if (this.Index == other.Index)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (this.Index > other.Index)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            ProductSortAttribute temp = obj as ProductSortAttribute;

            if (this.Index == temp.Index)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Index.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}--{1}--{2}", this.Index, this.ItemNumber, this.Description);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class ProductSortFactory
    {
        private ArrayList _products;
        public ProductSortComparer Sorter { get; set; }
        public ProductSortFactory(ArrayList products)
        {
            this._products = products;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the ProductSortComparer object for sorting
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>ProductSortComparer object to sort Collection of Products</returns>
        public ProductSortComparer GetComparer()
        {
            this.Sorter = new ProductSortComparer();
            this.Sorter.SortOrder = this.GetSortOrder();
            return this.Sorter;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds the sort order for a collection of Products.
        /// This is public as it can be accessed without returning the ProductSortComparer
        /// Which will provide a List<ProductSortAttribute> to look up indexes (sort position)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of ProductSortAttributes </returns>
        public List<ProductSortAttribute> GetSortOrder()
        {
            List<ProductSortAttribute> sortAttributes = new List<ProductSortAttribute>();// build sort attributes                
            List<String> group1 = new List<String> { "E", "F", "G", "R", "C", "A" };
            List<String> group2 = new List<String> { "B", "D", "S" };
            List<String> group3 = new List<String> { "J", "M", "Q" };
            List<String> group4 = new List<String> { "H", "I", "L" };
            List<String> group5 = new List<String> { "K", "N" };

            foreach (var item in this._products)
            {
                if (item is Product)
                {

                    Product product = item as Product;
                    ProductSortAttribute attribute = new ProductSortAttribute();
                    attribute.ItemNumber = product.ItemNumber.Trim();
                    attribute.Description = product.Description;
                    if (product.ItemNumber.Length > 9)
                    {
                        // find group
                        if (group1.IndexOf(product.ItemNumber.Substring(9, 1)) > -1)
                        {

                            if (product.MerchandiseCode != null && (product.MerchandiseCode.Contains('A') || product.MerchandiseCode.Contains('G')))
                            {
                                attribute.Index = 1; // make lower than E - E is full product and will float to top, but MerchandiseDescription 'A' will be lower 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                attribute.Index = 0;
                            }

                        }
                        else if (group2.IndexOf(product.ItemNumber.Substring(9, 1)) > -1)
                        {
                            attribute.Index = 2;
                        }
                        else if (group3.IndexOf(product.ItemNumber.Substring(9, 1)) > -1)
                        {
                            attribute.Index = 3;
                        }
                        else if (group4.IndexOf(product.ItemNumber.Substring(9, 1)) > -1)
                        {
                            attribute.Index = 4;
                        }
                        else if (group5.IndexOf(product.ItemNumber.Substring(9, 1)) > -1)
                        {
                            attribute.Index = 5;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        attribute.Index = 5;
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(attribute.ToString());
                    sortAttributes.Add(attribute);
                }
                else
                {

                    throw new InvalidCastException("ProductSorterFactory expects ArrayList of type Product");
                }

            }
            sortAttributes.Sort();
            return sortAttributes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I notice you're using `ArrayList`. Is this because of .NET version limitations?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The ArrayList is returned by a 3rd party API, so that is a limitation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CompareTo

This

```
public int CompareTo(ProductSortAttribute other)
{
    if (this.Index == other.Index)
    {
         return 0;
    }

    if (this.Index > other.Index)
    {
         return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

can be shortened to

```
public int CompareTo(ProductSortAttribute other) {
    return this.Index.CompareTo(other.Index);
}
```

Since `Int32` also implements `Comparable<T>`.

The same goes for ProductSortComparer#Compare inside the `if` statement: `return thisIndex.CompareTo(otherIndex);`

## Intermediate variables

Considering you never use `product1-5`, I would suggest to drop the intermediate variables (and whitespacing) and add it to your list immediately:

```
products.Add(
   new Product {
       ItemNumber = "MSBCDEFG1M01",
       Description = "Dell Computer Repair",
       MerchandiseCode = "E"
   }
);
```

## Loop casting

You can use LINQ to cast your `ArrayList()` with `Product` objects. If it contains invalid data, it will throw an `InvalidCastException` (which you already use manually).

Keep in mind that you don't perform a check whether or not it's a product everywhere. For example here you would end up with a `NullPointerException` (which will now be changed to an `InvalidCastExceptipn)`:

```
foreach (var product in products.Cast<Product>.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}--{1}", product.ItemNumber, product.Description));
}
```

## FirstOrDefault

I'm not entirely sure about this (not very comfortable around the LINQ expression syntax), so someone has to verify but I believe this

```
(from pair in otherTagged
 where pair.Item.ItemNumber == otherProduct.ItemNumber
 select pair.Index).FirstOrDefault();
```

is the same as

```
otherTagged.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ItemNumber == otherProduct.ItemNumber).Index;
```

Instead of first retrieving all products with that number, selecting all of their indices and then taking the first, I take the first product that has that number and take its index.

Edit: it's been pointed out to me by Mat's Mug that [there is a tiny performance difference between `.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()` and `.FirstOrDefault(predicate)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate) so you might want to keep this under consideration.

Comment: Nice answer. Regarding `FirstOrDefault` your suggestion will prove problematic if no item is found (the `OrDefault` part) - since it will cause a `NullPointerException`. If there is an expectation that an item will _always_ be found - use `First` instead.

Comment: @UriAgassi - interesting point as I am always weary using either First() or FirstOrDefault(). If I recall both can return `null` which could cause an `ArgumentNullException`. Usually I check for `null` and `Any()` before getting the `First` object. In this case, I was willing to take that chance.

Comment: @UriAgassi: good point, that's definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: @PhilVallone - http://geekswithblogs.net/berthin/archive/2011/07/22/linq_firstorfirstordefault.aspx

Comment: @UriAgassi - Thanks, it looks like they recommend to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` with `FirstOrDefault()` or `First()`. I prefer neither and check for `null` && `Any()`. But it all depends on if a `Default` is what works for you.

Comment: “You can use LINQ to cast your `ArrayList` with `Product` objects.” Or you can use `List<Product>` in the first place, there is no reason to use `ArrayList` in new code.

Comment: @svick: have you seen [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49350/dynamically-sorting-with-icomparer/49352?noredirect=1#comment86776_49350)? Or do you mean that regardless of that, you can omit the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Oh, I missed that. In that case, I would limit that `ArrayList` to the code that deals with that library by making the constructor of `ProductSortFactory` accept `IEnumerable<Product>` and use `Cast<Product>` on that `ArrayList` in the calling code. (And in the long term, try to run away from that API. :-))